# Do i need to use stream_set_blocking when using phpseclib?

Tags: php, phpseclib

I've been reading up on the differences between the [SSH2 library from PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2) and [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). It seems phpseclib is a little simpler to use and what not and the example codes I've found are minimal. With the SSH2 library, I've seen references to [`stream_set_blocking`](http://php.net/stream_set_blocking). Do I need to utilize this function with phpseclib?

Comment: Just wasn't sure if I need to utilize the function with Phpseclib. I see references to it with libssh2 but none with phpseclib.

Comment: You should ask about concrete problems, than this should be visible right ahead.

Comment: Awesome, you wasted valuable minutes of your life to tell me that. Kudos.

Comment: Well the question is not if the library needs that function but if you need it. Both libraries operate on streams and you can use `stream_set_blocking` with both of them. The question is, do you need to? I can not tell you if you need to or not. You haven't said either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used phpseclib for both SSH and SFTP and didn't need to use such a function.